# Change Datetime format

Tags: gnome, indicator

I'm using Gnome 3 / Gnome-shell, and Ubuntu 13.10.

I'd like to display the timestamp (as in, the number of seconds since 1970/01/01 00:00 UTC) next to the clock in the top bar. I figured out I just needed to change the time format and add a %s.

Then I searched where I could change the time format and found dconf keys `com.canonical.indicator.datetime.time-format` and `....custom-time-format`. I set the second one to "custom" (using dconf-editor) and the first one to `%l:%M %p   -   %s` but nothing changed. Actually, nothing in the whole dconf directory changed a single thing on the clock as I fiddled. (nor did logging off and on again)

I thought that it may come for gnome-tweak-tool overriding the settings, but I don't know how to make it use the standard parameters. When I change clock settings in gnome-tweak-tool, they're immediately used.

I've tried everything I could find on google... I'm even wondering if it would not be simpler to create my own locale, but I'm not even sure it will do the trick, as I don't know what gnome-tweak-tool (or some other software I'm not even aware) does to the clock...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe those settings only apply to Unity; gnome shell seems to store its clock settings in org.gnome.desktop.interface, but only allows you to set whether to display seconds and/or the date.

I had a quick look on the extensions site, though, and this seems to do what you are wanting: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/795/format-clock/

Comment: Since the question was asked, I moved to Unity, so I don't need an answer anymore (but I left the question open if it can be of any help for someone else). You solution was amonst the ones I tried (and sorry for not mentionning it in the first place) but, at least for me, the plug-in didn't work with the latest stable gnome 3 in precise. If anyone can validate that the plug-in works again, I'll be more than happy to close the question :)

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with a utility gnome clock or something.  searching...clock override.  you can set the date time format with any format you like.[this is mine if it will let you see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtDA5.png)

this is controlled by the %x formats in the manual.  search for clock override.